# Correct Way to Compare Floating-point Numbers

Tags: c++, c, floating-point, floating-accuracy

I'm calculating a real numeric value of the form `N + fraction`. Say, For example, `N + fraction = 7.10987623`, then `N = 7` and `fraction = 0.10987623` Next, I need to check to see if `fraction` is greater than or equal to the ratio `23269/25920`.

The following, in C/C++, appears to give correct results; however, I'm not sure if it is the correct way to do the comparison:

```
// EPSILON is defined to be the error tolerance
// and `ratio' is defined as 23269.0/25920.0 
if(fabs(fraction - ratio) > EPSILON)
 // `fraction' is greater or equal to `ratio'
```

I also tried to do the other way, but it appears to give incorrect results.

```
if(fabs(fraction - ratio) < EPSILON)
```

Comment: The result of `fabs(fraction - ratio)` says nothing about whether `fraction` is greater or less than `ratio`. When testing what you think is a correct approach, there are five relevant values of `fraction` to test: one much smaller than `ratio`, one just a tiny bit smaller than `ratio`, one exactly equal to `ratio` (even if `ratio` is not exactly 23269/25920), one just a tiny bit larger than `ratio`, and one much larger than `ratio`. If you test your two approaches like that, you'll find that neither works. If you write out your expected results for those five cases, you'll find the answer.

Comment: Voted for reopen, this question certainly has a lot of duplicates but the duplicate here was wrong.

Comment: How about comparing `fraction * 25920` and `23269`?

Comment: You have to define which way the error tolerance should go. What do you want to do if the ratio is very slightly greater than 23269/25920? What do you want to do if it's very slightly less?

Comment: @2501 Absolutely not a duplicate. That question is talking about equality `==`, this one is about ordering `<`. They may seem similar but in fact are totally different.

Comment: It doesn't look like you understand what David Schwartz is saying. Let me try to reformulate. The mathematical comparison tells you which of the two cases takes place, `(1) x < y` or `(2) x >= y`. You have two actions to perform, `do stuff when x < y` and `do other stuff when x >= y`. The decision is easy. The machine floating-point comparison, when implemented correctly, says which of the **three** cases takes place: `(1) x < y`, `(2) x > y` and `(3) x and y are too close to tell`. You need to either invent **three** corresponding actions, or lump two of the cases together.

Comment: Why use fabs? You know that both N and your ratio are positive? What are you trying to accomplish with EPSILON? Are you trying to guarentee that N > MAGIC_RATIO by at least EPSILON?

Comment: @n.m. Why don't you just write an answer?

Comment: @Barry Because I don't think it's the right thing to do in this case.

Answer (score 4):

You have the right way to compare equality:

```
fabs(fraction - ratio) < EPSILON
```

which establishes an equality band around `ratio` of width`EPSILON`. Anything *above* that band, is strictly greater. Thus, the `>` check is:

```
fraction > ratio + EPSILON
```

Since we want `>=`, we just take the union of those two sections:

```
fraction > ratio - EPSILON
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than specifying an `EPSILON`, which will need to vary depending on the magnitude of `N`, an alternative is to add `N` to `ratio`, as then both it and `fraction` will incur the same rounding:

```
x <= floor(x) + ratio
```

Answer (score 0):

Break a number into its whole number and fractional parts via `modf()`.
With a good FP library, no loss of precision would be expected.

```
#include <math.h>
int foo(double N_plus_fraction) {
  double ipart;
  double fraction = modf(N_plus_fraction, &ipart);
  fraction = fabs(fraction);  // lets use the absolution fraction.
```

Break the threshold into numerator/denominator parts and scale the fraction.

```
  double f = fraction*25920.0;
  return f >= 23269.0;
}
```

As the product `f` may not be an exact mathematical product of `fraction` and `25920.0`, but the closest rounded one,  code could use an `f` just slightly larger (or smaller) with `nextafter()` depending on which way one wants to bias the result.

```
  double f = fraction*25920.0;
  f = nextafter(f, 2*f);  // make f the next greater FP value.
  return f >= 23269.0;
}
```

The *only* inexactness expected occurs in the `fraction*25920.0` step.